# How to trim strings and list of strings in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
0              ['AU06_threshold_h', 'AU12_threshold_h']  
1                                     AU14_threshold_h   
2                                     AU26_threshold_h   
3                                                  NaN   
4                                     AU01_threshold_h
```

I want to trim the text from each string, as well as zeroes if the first character is a 0. It should look like this:

```
0              [6, 12]  
1                   14 
2                   26   
3                  NaN   
4                    1
```

Please advise. Thank you!

Comment: So you just want the numbers?

Comment: yes, just the numbers

Answer (score 1):

Using `explode`

```
df.col.explode().str.extract('(\d+)')[0]\
      .groupby(level=0).agg(lambda s: list(s) if len(s)>1 else s.iat[0])
```

---

```
0    [06, 12]
1          14
2          26
3         NaN
4          01
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

May I just say this is not a good design. Avoid having lists and numbers altogether in the same column.

Comment: Thanks @rafaelc . This mostly works, but when the item is a list, I only get the first value. For example, row 0 returns 06, not [06, 12].

Comment: The `apply` should be handling. Look at the function: `list(s) if len > 1` so should be returning the list and not a number. Are you sure you have the right code? p)

Answer (score 1):

With custom function (basing on regex substitution):

```
In [98]: pat = re.compile(r'[^\d]+')                                                                        

In [99]: def trim_non_num(s): 
    ...:     if isinstance(s, str): 
    ...:         return int(pat.sub('', s)) 
    ...:     elif isinstance(s, list): 
    ...:         return [int(pat.sub('', i)) for i in s] 
    ...:     return s 
    ...:                                                                                                    

In [100]: df['col'].apply(trim_non_num)                                                                     
Out[100]: 
0    [6, 12]
1         14
2         26
3        NaN
4          1
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks @RomanPerekhrest. This mostly works, but when the value is a list, it returns all the values together as 1 float. For example, row 0 is returned as 612.0, instead of [6, 12].